# How to traverse a "tilted" binary tree in c++ in levelorder?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree with the following structure:

[image: tilted binary tree]

...which I have been attempting to traverse as follows:
a b c d e f g h i j
My function is set up so that it takes the root the Node class of the binary tree, as well as a function print_node_data which prints the data associated with a given node when a node is passed to it.

```
template <typename TreeNode, typename FN>
void tlo(TreeNode *root, FN print_node_data)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;

    std::queue<TreeNode*> q;
    q.push(root);

    while (!q.empty()) {
            TreeNode* current = q.front();
            q.pop();

            //Print node data
            print_node_data(current);

            if (current->right)
            {
                auto temp = current;
                while (temp->right)
                {
                        q.push(temp->right);
                        print_node_data(temp->right);
                        q.pop();
                        temp = temp->right;
                }
            }
            if (current->left)
                q.push(current->left);
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far:
First, I was having the issue of the elements in the queue from c -> e not being deleted every pass of the outer while loop, so basically the next "current" element would be off and I would get the extended output:  a b c d e f d e e g h e h i j

The below is how I had set up my inner loop before:

```
if (current->right)
            {
                auto temp = current;
                while (temp->right)
                {
                        q.push(temp->right);
                        temp = temp->right;
                }
            }
}
```

Then, I attempted to solve the problem by adding the additional logic shown above where inside the loop I printed those right side elements, and then popped them from the queue. This helped slightly and gives me the new output:
a b c d e f g h

I then realized that I'm not handling the possibility of the nodes being processed by the inner loop having left children, which is why it stops short (it does not process g's left child and so on) so I attempted to store them in a variable and push them onto the queue -- but could not figure out how to do this outside of the while loop as they're being declared locally.

Any suggestions? I haven't found a lot of relevant documentation / examples on this specific scenario. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that this is a "tilted" tree is binary search tree whereby the ordering of nodes is inverted on each row. (top row is left to right, next row is RTL, then subsequent row is back to LTR again, repeat...).  Is that correct?

Comment: The order you want looks like DFS rather than BFS. DFS is usually done with a stack rather than a queue.

Comment: `q.push(temp->right); print_node_data(temp->right); q.pop();` Doesn't make sense. Why do you put a node on the queue if you are just about to visit it? Why are you popping some other node without ever looking at it?

Comment: The more I look at this, it looks to be binary search tree in which right comes before left in the traversal order. Can the OP confirm the definition of a "tilted" tree?

Comment: Yes, so basically this "tilted" tree was created by modifying a non-binary tree by tilting it by 45 degrees
Original tree had
Root A
B C D E (Children of A, LTR)
F G H (Children of B, LTR)
I J (Children of G, LTR)
The idea was to redefine the left child of a node to point to the node's first child on the non-binary tree and to redefine the right child of the node to point to the node's next sibling

Sorry for the confusion, I've never dealt with a tree with this setup before and am trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of a tilted tree just seems to imply a breadth first search but instead of the ordering of visit-left-right (VLR), it's just visit-right-left (VRL).  That is, a breadth first search that prefers right over left.

Maybe there's a more complex example in which my interpretation doesn't hold, but the code below will print out ABCDEFGHIJ as you discussed.

Hence, the algorithm is just this:

```
void tlo(TreeNode* root, FN print_node_data)
{
    if (root == nullptr) 
    {
        return;
    }
    print_node_data(root);
    tlo(root->right, print_node_data);
    tlo(root->left, print_node_data);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need a stack rather than a queue.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI - Breadth first search uses a queue, not a stack.

Comment: You need DFS not BFS. The recursive version is DFS.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI - ahh... my bad. you are correct.